# netbeans vs eclipse project structure comparision

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, struts

I use `Netbeans` and I have the same problem while learning from project that is written in Eclipse. In Eclipse, why is there another folder "Java Resources"? should not all the source files be in `- src/main/java`  and resources files in `- src/main/resources`?

Why use folder "Java Resources" to write source files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The folders you see in the Eclipse project explorer are not "real" folders. The source files are indeed in `src/main/java`, but Eclipse gives you a different view on these folders. Look at the Eclipse project in a file browser and you see the real structure.